# font size, div box size not changing while using append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I am trying to make a box with full width and a height of `150px` but it's not showing up the way I want nor the background color that I have set. Also, the text I write using the append function from jQuery is not changing it's font size.

html :

```
<div id = "header"></div>
```

css :

```
#header{
    height: 150px;
    width: 110%;
    font-size: 80px;
}
```

js :

```
$(target).append(message);
```

where target is #header

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the width to 110%, 100% will fill the whole screen width, other wise you get overflow.

Make sure you are selecting the right target to use append, and make sure you have jQuery included you javascript.

You are not setting any background color in you css in the first place, that's why no background color is viewing.

```js
$("#header").append("Test text");
```

```css
#header{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 80px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "header"></div>
```

Comment: well, i did exactly what you said and it's still not working, the font has the same size and the box or the border it;'s not even showing up. should i try to reset every the styling of everything trough css?

Comment: Try to check what css are really affecting your elements through the dev tools in chrome or firebug, right click your element and click 'inspect element', you'll see to the right the css applied on it and you can know if any other external files are effecting your element, as well as native browser css, try checking unchecking the element style to obtain live changes, then with some trial and error you might get to the real problem.